# Need review to my code in c language that computes and display the total amount of money the customer must pay

Tags: c, selection

*It is a program about asking the client to choose a vehicle to rent, and how many he wants*

> truck = 1100
> car=500

**Visual studio code gives me this message**

```
*warning: the result of comparison of constant 1920295787 with expression of type 'char' is*

always false [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
```

else if (vehicule == 'truck'){

here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int x, result;
char vehicule;

printf("what type of vehicule do need ? ");
scanf("%c", &vehicule);
printf("how many do you need ?");
scanf("%d",&x);
if (vehicule == 'car'){
result = x*500;
printf("the amount you need to pay is %d", result);}
else if (vehicule == 'truck'){
result = x*1100;
printf("the amount you need to pay is %d",result);}
else {
printf("error ");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to compare *strings* use `strcmp()` (not `==`), protoype in `<string.h>`. But you have more errors than this, especially *thinking* `'car'` is a string or that `"truck"` fits in a single `char`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of issues in your code. For example, you are mixing up what is a string and what is a character.

Here is a working copy of your program. Notice the changes!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // included for the usage of lib function strcmp

int main(){
    int x, result;
    char vehicle[6]; // this is a string of 5 charachters + the null charachter

    printf("what type of vehicule do need ? ");
    scanf("%s", vehicle); // Get input in string format
    
    printf("how many do you need ?");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    
    if (strcmp(vehicle, "car") == 0){ // Comapre the input with the string "car"
        result = x*500;
        printf("the amount you need to pay is %d", result);
    }
    else if (strcmp(vehicle, "truck") == 0){
        result = x*1100;
        printf("the amount you need to pay is %d",result);
    }
    else {
        printf("error ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```